# search in child entities by list criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I have root entity:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("MORAL")
public class MoralEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String internalId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_partner", nullable = true, updatable = true)
    private PartnerEntity partner;
    
}
```

which have relation to parent entity:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "pType", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class PartnerEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String internalId;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String pType;
    
}
```

And there is child entities:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("E1")
public class Entity1 extends PartnerEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<SpecialityEntity> specialities;

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("E2")
public class Entity2 extends PartnerEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<SpecialityEntity> specialities;

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("E3")
public class Entity3 extends PartnerEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

I want to search all MoralEntity where partner.specialities.code = "ABC", i tries like below but i have this error

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
> specialities of: PartnerEntity

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MoralEntity> query = cb.createQuery( MoralEntity.class );
Root<MoralEntity> root = query.from( MoralEntity.class );
Join<MoralEntity, PartnerEntity> partnerJoin = root.join( "partner" );

Predicate p1 = cb.equal( cb.treat( partnerJoin, Entity1.class ).join( "specialities" ).get( "code" ), "ABC" );

Predicate p2 = cb.equal( cb.treat( partnerJoin, Entity2.class ).join( "specialities" ).get( "code" ), "ABC" );

query.where( cb.or( p1, p2 ) );

List<MoralEntity> resultList = em.createQuery( query ).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug in Hibernate 5, but it is certainly fixed in 6.0+

If you can use HQL, I'm pretty sure that the following would work:

```
from MoralEntity m
join m.partner p
where exists(select 1 from p.specialities s where s.code = 'ABC')
```